# Publishing multiple packages from a Single Repository

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, bamboo

We have a single repository which contains multiple components and services(few of them are dependent on each other).

Each component and service is a node package.

We are using a Node script to generate Dist folder that contains all the component and services and separate node packages which are deployed to artifactory using Bamboo Build plan.

With this approach if there is a change in one component we are unnecessarily publishing  all the rest of the components to artifactory.

I am looking for a  best practice that if a component or service is changed only that component (And its dependency) gets published to Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

I have not much node experience, but from bamboo perspective what would occur to me here is to set up different build plans to build, package, and deploy each independent component.

A bamboo repository can be configured with an "include" regular expression.  If your node component source is in recognizable/matchable sub-folders in your repository, you could create a per-component set of repository definitions.  Each build plan for a particular component would use the appropriate repository definition, and only trigger if changes to that specific component are made.

Your publishing tasks would be slightly different for each components plan - since you know exactly which one you want to deploy, but you can clone a component A plan to create a component B plan, and change the repo and tasks appropriately.